# I want to get parent issue's custom field data to be inherited to subtask custom field

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api

I want to get parent issue's custom field data to be inherited to subtask custom field without using third party plugins.
Is there any way to do this by Groovy script or any plugin code

Answer (score 0):

How are you going to run your groovy script if you're not going to use a third-party add-on? Typically [Script Runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/server/overview) is used to do this because it allows you to easily [script fields](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/4.3.1/jira/scripted-fields.html), [postfunctions](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/4.3.1/jira/custom-workflow-functions.html) and/or [listeners](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/4.3.1/jira/listeners.html).

If you want to implement your own add-on, assuming you run a standalone JIRA and not a cloud JIRA, you can start [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/getting-started).

You then have different options to implement what you need. For JIRA Server you could:

- Use a [listener](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-platform/guides/other/tutorial-writing-jira-event-listeners-with-the-atlassian-event-library)
- Use a [postfunction](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-platform/building-jira-add-ons/jira-plugins2-overview/jira-plugin-module-types/workflow-plugin-modules#WorkflowPluginModules-Functions)
- Use a custom field. For tutorials look [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-platform/guides/fields/tutorial-creating-a-custom-field-type) and [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-platform/guides/fields/tutorial-custom-fields-in-jira).